# Excel Macro to convert xlsx to xls

Tags: excel, vba

i have bunch of files in folder all of them are in `xlsx` format, I need to convert them to `xls` format. This is going to be done on daily bases.

*I need a macro which will loop around the folder and convert the file to xls from xlsx with out changing file name.?*

Here is the macro I am using to loop

```
Sub ProcessFiles()
Dim Filename, Pathname As String
Dim wb As Workbook

Pathname = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "C:\Users\myfolder1\Desktop\myfolder\Macro\"
Filename = Dir(Pathname & "*.xls")
Do While Filename <> ""
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Pathname & Filename)
    DoWork wb
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
    Filename = Dir()
Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you are missing is that instead of calling `wb.Close SaveChanges=True` to save the file in another format, you need to call [`wb.SaveAs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185%28v=office.14%29.aspx) with the new file [format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017%28v=office.14%29.aspx) and name.

You said you want to convert them without changing the file name, but I suspect you really meant you want to save them with the same base file name, but with the `.xls` extension. So if the workbook is named `book1.xlsx`, you want to save it as `book1.xls`. To calculate the new name you can do a simple [`Replace()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264409%28v=office.14%29.aspx) on the old name replacing the `.xlsx` extension with `.xls`.

You can also disable the compatibility checker by setting [`wb.CheckCompatibility`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836165%28v=office.14%29.aspx), and suppress alerts and messages by setting [`Application.DisplayAlerts`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff839782%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

```
Sub ProcessFiles()
Dim Filename, Pathname, saveFileName As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim initialDisplayAlerts As Boolean

Pathname = "<insert_path_here>"  ' Needs to have a trailing \
Filename = Dir(Pathname & "*.xlsx")
initialDisplayAlerts = Application.DisplayAlerts
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Do While Filename <> ""
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Pathname & Filename, _
                            UpdateLinks:=False)
    wb.CheckCompatibility = False
    saveFileName = Replace(Filename, ".xlsx", ".xls")

    wb.SaveAs Filename:=Pathname & saveFileName, _
              FileFormat:=xlExcel8, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", _
              ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False

    wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Filename = Dir()
Loop
Application.DisplayAlerts = initialDisplayAlerts
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Sub SaveAllAsXLSX()
Dim strFilename As String
Dim strDocName As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim wbk  As Workbook
Dim fDialog As FileDialog
Dim intPos As Integer
Dim strPassword As String
Dim strWritePassword As String
Dim varA As String
Dim varB As String
Dim colFiles As New Collection
Dim vFile As Variant
Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With fDialog
    .Title = "Select folder and click OK"
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
    If .Show <> -1 Then
        MsgBox "Cancelled By User", , "List Folder Contents"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    strPath = fDialog.SelectedItems.Item(1)
    If Right(strPath, 1) <> "\" Then strPath = strPath + "\"
End With
If Left(strPath, 1) = Chr(34) Then
    strPath = Mid(strPath, 2, Len(strPath) - 2)
End If
Set obj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
RecursiveDir colFiles, strPath, "*.xls", True
For Each vFile In colFiles
        Debug.Print vFile
    strFilename = vFile
    varA = Right(strFilename, 3)
    If (varA = "xls" Or varA = "XLS") Then
     Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strFilename)
       If wbk.HasVBProject Then
              wbk.SaveAs Filename:=strFilename & "m", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
            Else
               wbk.SaveAs Filename:=strFilename & "x", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
            End If
            wbk.Close SaveChanges:=False
           obj.DeleteFile (strFilename)
    End If
Next vFile

End Sub
Public Function RecursiveDir(colFiles As Collection, _
                             strFolder As String, _
                             strFileSpec As String, _
                             bIncludeSubfolders As Boolean)

    Dim strTemp As String
    Dim colFolders As New Collection
    Dim vFolderName As Variant

    'Add files in strFolder matching strFileSpec to colFiles
    strFolder = TrailingSlash(strFolder)
    strTemp = Dir(strFolder & strFileSpec)
    Do While strTemp <> vbNullString
        colFiles.Add strFolder & strTemp
        strTemp = Dir
    Loop

    If bIncludeSubfolders Then
        'Fill colFolders with list of subdirectories of strFolder
        strTemp = Dir(strFolder, vbDirectory)
        Do While strTemp <> vbNullString
            If (strTemp <> ".") And (strTemp <> "..") Then
                If (GetAttr(strFolder & strTemp) And vbDirectory) <> 0 Then
                    colFolders.Add strTemp
                End If
            End If
            strTemp = Dir
        Loop

        'Call RecursiveDir for each subfolder in colFolders
        For Each vFolderName In colFolders
            Call RecursiveDir(colFiles, strFolder & vFolderName, strFileSpec, True)
        Next vFolderName
    End If

End Function
Public Function TrailingSlash(strFolder As String) As String
    If Len(strFolder) > 0 Then
        If Right(strFolder, 1) = "\" Then
            TrailingSlash = strFolder
        Else
            TrailingSlash = strFolder & "\"
        End If
    End If
End Function
```